# GWT rpc.SerializationException in a hibernate ManyToOne relationhip object

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, gwt, annotations

I wanted to develop a small GWT application with spring and hibernate but am getting an error while getting a list from MySql db. Entity class Contact has @ManyToOne relation with Room.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")

public **class Contact** extends LightEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
protected int id;   

@Column(name = "firstname")
protected String firstname;   

@Column(name = "telephone")    
protected String telephone;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_ID")  
protected Room room;
```

...setters and getters

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROOM")

public **class Room** extends LightEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ROOM_ID")
private int id;     

@Column(name = "ROOM_NUMBER")    
protected int rnr;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="room", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) // tried to fetch eagerly
private List<Contact> contacts;
```

...setters and getters

LightEntity has been used as expained in article https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate?hl=fr-FR

When i use only **uni-directional** (i.e. Contact to Room with @ManyToOne) relationship then it **works fine**.

Here is the exception:-

```
Hibernate: select contacts0_.ROOM_ID as ROOM6_1_1_, contacts0_.id as id1_, contacts0_.id as id0_0_, contacts0_.email as email0_0_, contacts0_.firstname as firstname0_0_, contacts0_.lastname as lastname0_0_, contacts0_.ROOM_ID as ROOM6_0_0_,  contacts0_.telephone as telephone0_0_ from contact contacts0_ where contacts0_.ROOM_ID=?

Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: 
Type 'org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. 

For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.:
instance = [com.project.server.schema.Contact@168e461, com.project.server.schema.Contact@dde1f6,  com.project.server.schema.Contact@c66a3b, com.project.server.schema.Contact@8103d8, com.project.server.schema.Contact@137dfac]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:619)
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Kind regards,
Abid

Comment: First thing:
Do you have an empty constructor for this class? It's mandatory for GWT serialization.

Comment: Yes both entity classes have empty constructors.

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem disappeard when I used @LazyCollection:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
```

Complete example:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, optional=false)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinColumn(name="room_id")
public Room getRoom();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
public List<Contact> getContacts();
```

Comment: Thanks binarious for your suggestion, but unfortunately, its still throwing same exception...

Comment: Did you remove the `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`, too?

Comment: And make sure you use the latest version of Gilead and use `import net.sf.gilead.pojo.gwt.LightEntity;` instead of the outdated `java5` package google refers to.

Comment: Thanks binarious, well i did as you suggested but same exception is thrown.

Comment: Problem solved by adding the following annotation:-  'code'
**@OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")  <br>
@GwtTransient         
private List<Contact> contacts;**